# ExtJS 3.2: Hide central panel at layout "border"

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, border, extjs3

[image]

Hello! In my project I have a window, whose structure is described on a picture. For some reasons, inherited from the previous versions of the project, I need to create a function that will hide parts of the window (panels). If I hide the panel C2 - everything is fine, works exactly as I wanted, but if I hide the panel C1, which has region: "center", the other panel does not occupy the region C1. It looks like a bug.

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I still  need some kind of hack to hide the central panels.

I tried to reassign the region: "center" to the other panel, but it did not work.

[test case](http://pastehtml.com/view/brbconfbr.html)

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to hide the c1 panel?

Comment: http://pastehtml.com/view/brbconfbr.html, right click -> view sources. c1.hide(); c1.parent.doLayout() - firebug console.

Comment: You are right when you say you should change the region of the panels. The one that is gonna be hidden always has to be anything different than "center". Try changing the region before hiding the element.

Comment: I tried, but i don't know how to... c2.region = 'center'; - don't work. parent.removeAll(false); c2.region = 'center'; c1.region ='west'; parent.add(c1); parent.add(c2) - don't work... Can you explain me how to do that after render?

Comment: You can use the `beforerender` event that gets fired before the component is rendered. But still, I'm pretty sure the border layout is static, so you can't change anything. It's probably better for you to have the center region as a placeholder panel with a FitLayout ("fit"). From there, add/remove your items from this panel to simulate changing the center.

Comment: layout "fit" - looks like solution. but some hack for "border" - still better. tnx.

Comment: Well, I think when you work with legacy versions you need to go through that kind of stuff. Try switching to ExtJS 4, and you will have better days!

Comment: I have over 20 000 lines of code for ExtJS3((

Comment: I think that i can use only "border" layout, because i need in splitters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS does not allow to remove center panel of a border layout. However you can add and remove items from the center panel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you specify a fixed width for the c2 panel:

```
var c1 = new Ext.Panel({
    region: "center",
});                

var c2 = new Ext.Panel({
    region: "east",
    width: 400,
    split: true
});
```

And that makes your c1 panel to get lost when hiding because of its region property.

When you work with region, you usually don't set fixed width. That is gonna solve your problem:

```
var c1 = new Ext.Panel({
    region: "center",
});                

var c2 = new Ext.Panel({
    region: "east",
    width: "100%",
    split: true
});
```

You can now try either `c1.hide();` or `c2.hide()` and the components will behavior like expected.